# windows 2008 remote access, a better way to open FW for dynamic IP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, firewall, dynamic-ip

I need to access to a remote SQL-Server database on a Windows 2008 Std Server. The administrator told me they can open my IP on FW but, I have a dynamic IP.

Do you know another simple way to access to the database regarding security?

Can I grant access if I'm using dyndns.org service o something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically you would VPN into the network first then access the server.  Is that not an option?

Comment: Because I borrowed the server, I'm looking for the simplest solution, VPN will be the last card.

Answer (score 1):

This greatly depends on the firewall they're using, but I don't think dyndns will help.

You could ask them to open up your current IP in the firewall, and they can modify that if need be (I know my dynamic IP is pretty ... static).  You could also ask them if they have a VPN solution they would like you to use instead.

Comment: They are using the standard Windows 2008 firewall. My provider renews the IP every time I logged in, could be ones a day!